# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound error using flask and python

Tags: python

WHY IT DOES NOT SHOW WHAT I'VE WRITTEN IN HOME.HTML AND IT RESULTS TO THAT ERROR?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

app.debug = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do have to specify the port in the `app.run()` call like `app.run(port=8080, debug=True)`. Also check whether `home.html` is existing in the `templates` folder.

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much for that help. I forgot to includes that file in templates folder. One more thing, does it really need that the folder name is templates?

Comment: Glad it helped!...yeah, as far as I know, the `.css` files are included in a folder called `static` and the `.html` files in a folder called `templates`.